# Can I use 'for' loop in react (babel js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

(*first, sorry my English is not good*)

I'm not an expert, I'm not sure. But what I want is to add as many node as I want.

It's work when I didn't use 'for' loop :

```
<script type="text/babel">
function addnode(){
    var node = (
        <div className="node"></div>
    )
    ReactDOM.render(
        node,
        document.getElementById("root")
    )
}
addnode();
</script>
```

result :

```
<div id="root"><div data-reactroot="" class="node"></div></div>
```

---

but It's not work (
*I don't know if I did it right. But the problem is the for loop.*):

```
<script type="text/babel">
function addnode(){
    var node = ""
    for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
        node += (
            <div className="node"></div>
        )
    }
    ReactDOM.render(
        node,
        document.getElementById("root")
    )
}
addnode();
</script>
```

error code :

```
babel.min.js:27 Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token (4:28)

 function setseat(){
     var node = ""
     for(var i=0; i&lt;20; i++){
                         ^
         node += (
             <div className="node"></div>
         )
```

Is there another way to use this correctly or to replace it?

Comment: You can use loops, but you cannot use `+=`

Comment: @Bergi I got it  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. But you need to know a few things.

1. **Root element should be only one.**
2. **Use `Array.prototype.map` for rendering list element.**

You are trying to use each of the lists as root. To solve this, you need to wrap the list using `<div></div>` tag.

```html
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
      </body>
    </html>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
    function addnode(){
        let node = [];
        for(var i=0; i<20; i++){
            node.push(i);
        }
        const contents = node.map(each=>{
          return (
            <div key={each} className={each}>{each}</div>
          )
        });
        const wrapper = (
          <div className="wrapper">
            {contents}
          </div>
        );
        ReactDOM.render(
            wrapper,
            document.getElementById("root")
        )
    }
    addnode();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use map function to loop in React.

Say you have couple of elements, arrayList..

```
render(){
    var arrayList = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
    return(
    {    <ul>
             arrayList.map(function(a){return <li key={a}>{a}</li>
         </ul>
    })
    )
}
```

Just have your map's callback return a html element